# JVM tomcat : Threads move from multi cores to single core with load

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, tomcat, jvm

Deployed a war on tomcat that does a lot of I/O operations and has a few huge files as trained datasets.
Now initially when the webapp was hit the load was distributed across all the cores (8) and over time all the load started to move to a single core. The thread dump showed all the tasks were stuck on CPU and top/htop revealed the same.

Any idea what could be the reason for this behavior ?

Comment: You forgot to tell us what the problem is! Was performance poor? What do you mean by "the tasks were stuck on CPU" exactly? It may just be that the I/O was the limiting factor. And what CPU was this? It may be a CPU that has a higher clock speed when only one core is loaded. (So if it's I/O bound, loading other cores actually just makes things slightly worse.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Yes extremely bad performance. I just started hitting the webapp till I got all the CPU's at 100% which was giving a high QPS and everything running well. A thread dump at this point showed threads waiting on I/O but then keeping the same amount of load for more time led to this situation where slowly each core had no load and only one core being active. Thread Dump a this point revealed that the threads were stuck at random CPU operations in the app nothing specific to I/O.

Comment: @trutheality this was prod server and pretty sure no such power optimizations were done

Comment: Off-topic for SO; belongs on [sf]

Comment: Dont think so ... I am speculating JVM does some kind of thread optimisations if all the threads are using the same resources ... will try volatile type on those resources and see that makes any difference

Comment: It might be worth asking on SF -- because it sounds like an OS optimization, not a JVM optimization -- the JVM just spawns threads, and the OS decides what cores to assign them to. The only optimization that the JVM does over time is JIT compilation, but that shouldn't affect the distribution of threads to cores.